# Is there any server side check for commenting permissions?

Tags: support, comments, validation

Users can earn a privilege *comment everywhere* when their reputation reaches 50. Yes, I can comment on any questions or answers already. You can blame me for trying to test this.

On one question, I used *FireBug* plugin and tried to change the question ID (at least, I assume so). For instance:

```
        <div data-localized="true" class="comments dno" id="comments-xxxxxx">
        <table>
            <tbody data-addlink-disabled="false" data-addlink-html="add comment" data-remaining-comments-count="0">
                    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
            </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="comment-form">
                            <form data-placeholdertext="blah blah.." class="" id="add-comment-xxxxx"></form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here `xxxx` must be changed to the same ID (the ID of a real answer or question). After I changed these to another post ID, I added comments. And indeed, this comment will be posted to that answer or question for which I inserted the ID. To see the comments, I opened the other question page with:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/xxxxx/
```

I am assuming that Stack Exchange doesn't validate comments on the server side.

I am correct? I am concerned about someone stupid using programattical means (for example, using [HTML UNIT](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)). Won't that lead to problems for Stack Exchange? Any explanation?

Comment: Sorry, what? I don't quite follow the issue here.

Comment: I am still noob in programming. so you can blame me for my stupid questions.

Comment: I guess he's asking if comment-privilege validation only happens on the client-side @Oded ...

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear; are you saying it's possible to post comments without having the privaledge using this method?

Comment: I admit , I had tested like that just only one but now I deleted it.
:)

Comment: @RichardTingle - From the code, I **think** the OP is saying they can change the id attribute and post a comment on a different post, not on the current page.

Comment: Could you link to where you've used this to post a comment without having the privaledge?

Comment: @ Richard Tingle , no I mean I comment on question or answer A but that may post to question or answer B.

Comment: @Cataclysm - Are you saying the problem is that it is possible to end up commenting on post X instead of post Y even if the UI belongs on post Y?

Comment: If so, can you explain **why this is a problem**?

Comment: @Cataclysm Is that a problem, if someone wants to post a comment on answer B and has the privileges to do so then thats fine. If they want to use a really mad way to achieve that then thats fine too

Comment: @ Richard Tingle, I described , programatically read them and add comments.

Comment: @Cataclysm Ok, and what problem would that cause; reading comments is already officially possible by API and I believe writing comments will be soon as well (and I'm sure is unofficially possible already in a hundred different ways)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters , Thanks for your valuable edited to my question. Yes , I means as you edited. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we do check if the logged in user has the permissions to comment on the server side.

We don't trust the client.

---

Now, you seem to be concerned about the ability to *script* a commenting bot of some sort - this is not an issue because comments are rate limited. We only allow commenting every 5 seconds.

<s>Additionally, if enough comments by the same user get flagged, I believe a comment ban come into play.</s>

So, this is a scenario we do handle.

Comment: I realize that.. when I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316550/which-way-to-disable-firebug-in-my-website. If so, you need to handle from server site for this.

Comment: For **what**? I still don't understand **what the problem** you are trying to describe is.

Comment: I mean I comment on question or answer A but that may post to question or answer B.

Comment: @Cataclysm - Yes, I understand that. What I **don't understand** is why you think this is a problem.

Comment: I described , programatically read them and add comments. Can you think how many questions and answers ?

Comment: @Cataclysm - First of all, you can only post a comment every 5 seconds. Second, if you post nonsense comments, they will get flagged and you would end up being banned (manually, by moderators). And all this is done server side. So - what exactly do you see to be a problem here?

Comment: Hmm... great ! I think wrong posting comments may worse things.

Comment: "Yes, we do check if the logged in user has the permissions to comment on the server side." as you said . I know commenting on post need define reputations..OK ! why not this guy can do it ?

Comment: Yes, finally , I accept your edited answer. Thanks for your valuable times.

Comment: @Cataclysm - What guy? Where? A user can comment on their own post, always. If they asked a question, they can comment on the answers as well.

Comment: I've never heard of a comment ban. It was remotely mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81526/semi-automated-suspension) (in the first revision) but never really with proof it got implemented. Can you please check the codez and see if such thing exists? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I could be imagining things, based on discussions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - No, it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah.. really ? I think as you described this has been implemented. :)

Comment: @Cataclysm - The comment ban has not been implemented yet. But the moderators will end up suspending a user that abuses comments in this manner.

Comment: very well ! fine ! I get knowledges from you. Thanks for all.

Comment: @Oded "yet" means it's planned?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I don't think that any discussions made it far enough for a spec, let alone planning to do it. But "yet" means something _may_ happen in the future ;)

Comment: @Oded so diplomatic, as always!